# Break a 7 digit number into multiple variables in PHP

Tags: php

We have a "potential" 7 digit number that we need to break into 7 separate variables. If it is a 4 digit number, then the other 3 digits should be empty. As an example:

```
$total = 12345 

$var1 = ""
$var2 = ""
$var3 = "1"
$var4 = "2"
$var5 = "3"
$var6 = "4"
$var7 = "5"
```

Anyone have any ideas on the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: do you want `$var1` and `$var2` to be declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split, then pad:

```
$a = 123456;
$arr = array_pad(str_split($a), -7, "");
```

See [output.](http://ideone.com/w191bG)

And if you absolutely need 7 variables:

```
$a = 123456;
$arr = array_pad(str_split($a), -7, "");
$i = 1;
foreach($arr as $s)
    ${"var".$i++} = $s;
```

But I strongly suggest using an array.

Answer (score 5):

You will need:

- [`str_split`](http://php.net/str_split)
- [`array_pad`](http://php.net/array-pad)

Should be easy enough to figure out. But seriously, use an array instead of `$var1`, `$var2`...

Comment: sorry, it was too harsh. When i downvoted there wasn't last line there. As a punishment I wear a n00b hat today.

Answer (score 0):

If `$total` is a positive integer, `$total % 10` will give you the last digit.  Integer division by 10 will remove the last digit.

```
$digits = array();
for ($i = $total; $i > 0; $i = (int)$total/10) {
    array_unshift($digits, $total % 10);
}
```

Comment: It might be more constructive to say that this would be more efficient with an array and a loop.

Comment: Sorry @Kolink, I was just trying to show a different idea, not get caught up in the details.  Better?

Answer (score 0):

As said by most of them, using array and loop is appropriate, still if you dont want to use the array.

Try this:

```
<?php
 $total=12345;
 $totaldigits=strlen((string)$total);
 while($totaldigits!=0){
   $var=$total%10;
   $total=$total/10;
   $totaldigits--;
   echo 'Digit '.$totaldigits.':'.$var.'<br/>';
 }
 ?>
```

I could not put them in different variables as you want. For that you will have to use the array.

## edit 1:

In case you change your mind,

```
$total=12345;
$num_arr=array();
$spaceneeded=7-strlen((string)$total);//the no. of array elements to be kept empty as per the total number of digits
$i=$spaceneeded;
$totaldigits=strlen((string)$total);
while($totaldigits!=0){
  $var=$total%10;
  $total=$total/10;
  $totaldigits--;
  for($j=0;$j<$spaceneeded;$j++){
    $num_arr[$j]=""; 
   }
  $num_arr[$i]=$var;
  $i++;
}
```

See if this helps.